# Is there a standard construct for 'choose<bool,typename,typename>'?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, conditional-statements

I sometimes find myself in need for the following:

```
template<bool B, typename T1, typename T2>
struct choose{
  typedef T1 type;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct choose<false, T1, T2>{
  typedef T2 type;
};
```

I use this to conditionally choose one type or the other. Now, is there already something in the standard library that does exactly this? [Boost.MPL has something similar](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/if.html), but that isn't exactly the same (takes a type, not a bool) and I don't want to include Boost for this little thing. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:  it is called `std::conditional` in C++0x (or `boost::conditional` in Boost).

The `boost::mpl::if` that you cite has a corresponding `boost::mpl::if_c` that takes a `bool` instead of a type; this is a common pattern in the Boost type traits libraries.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I wanted. :) Now just a little template typedef to shorten that...