# C++ how to implement conditional inheritance with the following example

Tags: c++, inheritance

What I want to doe is a simple conditional inheritance in the Foo class
 so depending on how it's instanciated (see usage)

```
class BaseType
{
  protected:
  m_valueX;
  public: BaseType(int param = 0):m_valueX(param){}
  ~ BaseType(){}
 }
```

...

```
 class Type1 : public BaseType
 {
  public: Type1():BaseType(1){}
  ~Type1(){}         
 }
```

...

```
 class Type2 : public BaseType
 {
  public: Type2(): BaseType(2){}
  ~Type1(){}         
 }
```

...

```
 template<typename Base>
 class Foo: public Base
 {

  public:
  Foo(){}
  ~Foo();
  void dothis();
  }
```

...........

in cpp file

```
template<typname Base>
Foo<Base>::Foo():Base()
{
}

Foo::~Foo(){}

void Foo::dothis(){}
```

usage:

```
Foo* fooptr1 = new Foo<Type1>();<== error use of class template requires template argument list
Foo* fooptr2 = new Foo<Type2>();>();<== error use of class template requires template argument list
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foo` is a template, not a class. The common class type for all `Foo<T>` is `Base`, so you can say:

```
Base * p1 = new Foo<Type1>;
Base * p2 = new Foo<Type2>;
```

Comment: ok I see your point thank you very much. but this answer from another post does is for my current problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779938/conditionally-inheriting-from-either-of-two-classes